# How to sort scala maps by length of the key (assuming keys are strings)

Tags: scala, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort a scala map by key length. The map looks something like:

```
val randomMap = Map("short" -> "randomVal1", "muchlonger" -> "randomVal2")
```

I want to sort randomMap such that when I iterate over it, I will start with the longest key first...so it should iterate over the "muchlonger" element first.

Comment: A [Map (or Associative Array)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) is generally unordered - that is, the simple ADT does not provide such order guarantees. One could use a `List[Tuple2[..]]` (or other sequence of key-value pairs, etc) to maintain the ordering after a sort operation. Alternatively, see [SortedMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SortedMap.html) if accessing by key is still important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it to a sequence of key/value pairs and apply a sorting criteria. eg.:

```
randomMap.toSeq.sortBy(_._1.length).reverse
```

(reverse because it sorts by shortest to longest by default).

Comment: Or just use `randomMap.toSeq.sortBy(-_._1.length)` and skip the intermediate collection.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to define a custom ordering for a `TreeMap`. `TreeMap` is a sorted implementation of `Map`

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

implicit object LengthOrder extends Ordering[String] { 
    def compare(s1: String, s2: String) = s1.length - s2.length 
}

val randomMap = TreeMap("111" -> "111", "1" -> "1", "11" -> "11")

//randomMap: TreeMap[String,String] = Map(1 -> 1, 11 -> 11, 111 -> 111)

val keys = randomMap.keys
//keys: Iterable[String] = Set(1, 11, 111)
```

Note that this will affect all `TreeMap[String]`s where `LengthOrder` is in scope. In your project you could nest `LengthOrder` in another `object` (or put it in its own package) and then only import it inside the specific code blocks that need it.

---

*Edit:*

@Bharadwaj made a good point about how this would destroy all but one keys that have the same length. Something like this would fix this issue:

```
implicit object LengthOrder extends Ordering[String] { 
    def compare(s1: String, s2: String) = s1.length - s2.length match {
      case 0 => s1.compareTo(s2)
      case x => x
    }
}
```

Comment: this will knock off one of the keys from a map which has 2 keys of equal length. dangerous!

Comment: Good catch. I've made an edit with a `Ordering` that fixes this issue.